# Modifying Symfony form data after failed validation

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've got a Symfony form field with a custom validator. If the user submits the form and validation fails, I'd like to correct the value and show it to the user for review.

How can I modify a submitted form field *after* validation?

`PRE_SUBMIT` isn't suitable as it's executed before the validation:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($options) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    $data['myField'] = 'Modified!';

    $event->setData($data);
});
```

I've also tried making the modification in the controller, but I get a `You cannot change the data of a submitted form` error.

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
    $form->get('myField')->setData('Modified!');
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Form events won't work here because they fire before validation. Look into custom form types and view transformers.

Comment: @BillH Thanks Bill, I tried a view transformer but the submitted data overrides the value.

Comment: Just an idea, but couldn't you create a new form and pass in the data from the old form when the validation fails and then render that?

Comment: Did you try FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT event?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a submitted value and its corrected value? Is there an algorithm for determining the correct value?

Answer (score -1):

How is this way?

```
$myValue = '';
if ($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid()) {
    $myValue = 'Modified!';
}
return $this->render('my_template.html.twig', [
    'form' => $form->createView(),
    'myValue' => $myValue,
]);
```

In `my_template.html.twig`,

```
{{ form_widget(form.myField, {'value' : myValue}) }}
```